# ssh command and quotes

Tags: linux, ssh

What is the difference between execution `ssh` command followed by remote command with and quotes and the remote command without quotes?

E.g. what is the difference between:

```
ssh remotehost tar xf archivename.tar
```

and

```
ssh remotehost "tar xf archivename.tar"
```

or what is the difference between:

```
ssh remotehost <path to script>/myscript.sh param
```

and

```
ssh remotehost "<path to script>/myscript.sh param"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing arguments are combined into a single string which is passed to as an argument to the `-c` option of your login shell on the remote machine. In your first example, there is little difference. However, consider the following:

```
$ ssh remotehost echo *
```

Here, `*` is expanded locally, and the result is passed to the remote machine. On my machine, my working directory consisted of a single entry containing an apostrophe (single quote), so the remote host tried to run a command like

```
bash -c "echo chepner's folder"
```

which of course resulted in an error.

```
$ ssh remotehost "echo *"
```

Now the remote host gets a literal `*`, but it is subject to shell expansion before being passed to `bash -c`. As a result, you output all the files in your home directory on the remote host.

```
$ ssh remotehost "echo \*"
```

Finally, the remote shell gets a *quoted* asterisk in its input, so you get a single literal `*` as output.

Comment: and what happens if I write `ssh remotehost rm -rf $dir/*`?

Comment: The variable and glob will expand on the client side, and any files with those names will be deleted on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes prevents expansion of special characters.

Imagine if there were any in your command you want to execute remotely (`;, &, &&, |, ||, >, >>` etc.). They would take effect before actually getting to your remote host, because bash would not know that all of it is just an argument to `ssh`.

Also, if the path to your script contained more spaces, they'd get lost and script wouldn't be found.