# What difference does ssh command quoting make?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, quotes, quoting

How is it that these commands result in different output?

```
⋊> ssh host bash -c 'cd /tmp; pwd'
/home/manu
⋊> ssh host "bash -c 'cd /tmp; pwd'"
/tmp
```

An answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431540/1633985) states that:

> The trailing arguments are combined into a single string which is passed to as an argument to the -c option of your login shell on the remote machine.

In case of an `*` I can understand this, but what part would be evaluated locally in this example? Also, an `--` before the bash command doesn't help.

Comment: See this post: [Strange 'sh -c' behavior when run through ssh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340221/strange-sh-c-behavior-when-run-through-ssh)

Comment: @codeforester, ...though I think this deserves an answer that goes beyond `sh -c`, since it's certainly an issue that's relevant in other scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing to understand here is that `ssh` simply concatenates its arguments (in the same way that `$*` does), and passes that concatenated string to `sh -c`.

---

Thus, in the case of:

```
ssh josh-play bash -c 'cd /tmp; pwd'
```

...ssh runs:

```
sh -c 'bash -c cd /tmp; pwd'
```

...thus, sh runs:

```
bash -c cd /tmp
pwd
```

...and as you can test yourself, `bash -c cd /tmp` doesn't do much that's useful (the script text it runs consists only of `cd`; `/tmp` is stored as an argument, but the script text never reads its arguments, making that moot). Moreover, as soon as `bash` exits, we're back in the parent `sh` process, in which `cd` was never run.

The syntactic quotes passed to your outer shell are entirely lost, and the `pwd` is invoked not by the `bash` that you manually triggered (which, in this usage, simply invokes `cd` without any arguments -- `/tmp` is in `$1`, but the script passed as an argument to `cd` never dereferences that variable) but by the `sh` that ssh implicitly invokes.

---

If you know that your remote `sh` is provided by bash or ksh -- a shell supporting the `$''` extension -- you can do the following for any arbitrary argv array (in this case `bash`, `-c`, `cd /tmp; pwd`):

```
# ask your shell to generate an eval-safe quoted form of your argument list
printf -v rmt_cmd '%q ' bash -c 'cd /tmp; pwd'

# pass that through to be run by the remote sh -c
ssh josh-play "$rmt_cmd"
```

The caveat to the above is that if your argument list can contain newlines or hidden characters, `printf %q` in bash or ksh can escape it in a form that POSIX sh isn't guaranteed to be able to read. To avoid that:

```
# ask your shell to generate an eval-safe quoted form of your argument list
printf -v rmt_cmd '%q ' bash -c 'cd /tmp; pwd'

# ...and use bash to evaluate that quoted form.
ssh josh-play 'exec bash -s' <<<"$rmt_cmd"
```